# How can I pass variables from one function to another function that already has a $request argument(In the same controller)

Tags: laravel-5.3

Please note that my problem is not how to pass variables from one function to another. My problem is that the function supposed to receive the variables already has a '$request' argument(from a form, to be stored in the database along side the variables I want to pass to it) so this causes it to flag an error.

class PingController extends Controller
{

```
public $long;
public $lat;
public function getPostAdd($longitude, $latitude){

    $this->long = $longitude;
    $this->postForm();
    $this->lat = $latitude;
    $this->postForm();
    return view('form');
}

public function postForm(Request $request){
    $ping = new Ping();
    $ping->longitude = dd($this->long);
    $ping->latitude = dd($this->lat);
    $ping->title = $request->input('title');
    $ping->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $ping->description = $request->input('description');
    $ping->organization = $request->input('organization');

    Auth::user()->pings()->save($ping);
    return "Data saved in database";
}
```

}

It gives this error:

FatalThrowableError in PingController.php line 23:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\PingController::postForm() must be an instance of Request, none given, called in C:\Users\CAESAR\Desktop\eepme\app\Http\Controllers\PingController.php on line 17

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.

However, if you can't pass your `$request` object to the `postForm` function, you can also retrieve the request object by using the global `request()` helper. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-request)

```
public function postForm()
{
    $ping = new Ping();
    $ping->longitude = dd($this->long);
    $ping->latitude = dd($this->lat);
    $ping->title = request()->title;
    $ping->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $ping->description = request()->description;
    $ping->organization = request()->organization;

    Auth::user()->pings()->save($ping);
    return "Data saved in database";
}
```

Comment: So now would it be something like:
public function postForm()
{
    $request = request();
    $ping = new Ping();
    $ping->longitude = dd($this->long);
    $ping->latitude = dd($this->lat);
    $ping->title = request()->title;
    $ping->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $ping->description = request()->description;
    $ping->organization = request()->organization;

    Auth::user()->pings()->save($ping);
    return "Data saved in database";
}

Answer (score 0):

You can inject request object in your first method and use it to call the second one. This won't affect your route parameters.

```
public function getPostAdd(Request $request, $longitude, $latitude){

    $this->long = $longitude;
    $this->postForm(request);
    $this->lat = $latitude;
    $this->postForm(request);
    return view('form');
}
```

This answers your question, but your whole implementation is flawed and pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks. I started laravel last month and this is my first project, so please understand. What would be a better way to go about  it?

Comment: If you give me a brief explanation of what you're trying to achieve then i'll guide you

Comment: Ok. How can we move this to chat please?

Comment: Alright you can leave your messages in the chat and i can help you in the morning when i check them, since you haven't come on it yet.

Comment: turns out I don't have the required amount of reputation to join a chat. But basically this is what I'm trying to do: when users come on the website, they see a button on the homepage. When they click the button, it gets their location(Longitude and Latitude) and through a route, passes it to the function getPostAdd. This function then returns a form asking for some additional details. The user details collected on the form and their location should then be saved to database by postForm function. And yes I want to collect their location first before their details, not together.